# compare color of two images with ruby rmagick

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I have two PNG images:
 - "image1.png" contains 100 circle points with different colors.
 - "image2.png" also contains 100 circle points with different colors.

However, the problem is that points in **"image1.png" file are bigger than points in "image2.png"** file. (Note that I cropped these images from the large images that contains them, then they have different sizes).

There is any way to verify whether color of 100 points displayed in "image1.png" file are the same/different to color of points displayed in "image2.png" using Ruby Rmagick ? Or any suggestion to be able to compare two images in this situation is much appreciated. Thanks much.

Comment: Please could you attach the images in question (or a simplified example), to help SO readers understand it. Do you know the position of the circles as (x,y) co-ordinates? If you do, then this can be done by reading the pixels - some code from where you obtain the centre x,y co-ords of the circles would be a good start to show you have tried something . . .

Comment: Neil Slater, I attached two images as your suggest. However, actually, I cropped them from large images that contain circles. So, they are in different sizes. I googled around and around and see that it's very difficult to compare color of points in two images in this case. However, it's much appreciated if you know a way to guide me. Thanks again.

Comment: I think you will need to take this in stages, and write some temporary code to help you understand. First, you need to figure out a way to calculate the x,y position of a given circle that you want to compare in each image. Just the centre, form the images that looks do-able. You can use `rmagic` on a copy of the image as a test, and plot the point in a new colour - e.g. red, just to show you have found the right position. The relevant `rmagic` docs are here: http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#pixel_color

Comment: @Neil Slater, I just think an idea from your instruvtion. I will use pixel_color method of Rmagick to get color of each circle point on "image1.png", then also use pixel_color method to get color of each circle point on "image2.png". So, if the returned RGB for first circle of image1 is equal to the returned RGB color for first circle of image2, then two images are the same color. And, I will do compare for the remaining circles. What do you think about that ?

Comment: That is a fine idea. The difficult bit, if the images are different sizes, is calculating where the circles are. If you get stuck with that, post the code you have so far.